# MySQL Joins - getting all data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to get data from three different tables at once, and I don't think I quite understand joins correctly, as I'm getting nowhere fast.
For example, lets say the tables are `houses`, `sellers`, and `selling_details`. `houses` and `sellers` are linked by the `selling_details`: it has a `seller_id` and a `house_id`, plus more information such as price, and a link to a user.

I want to build a query that returns all houses in the system, matched up to all sellers, and list the selling details if present. For example:

```
+------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------+-----------+
| house.name | seller.name | selling_details.details | selling_details.date | user.name |
+------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------+-----------+
| One        | One         | details                 | 2011-02-18           | bobby     |
| One        | Two         | details                 | 2011-02-24           | frank     |
| One        | Three       | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL      |
| One        | Four        | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL      |
| Two        | One         | details                 | 2011-01-16           | ned       |
| Two        | Two         | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL      |
| Two        | Three       | details                 | 2011-02-12           | will      |
| Two        | Four        | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL      |
+------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------+-----------+
```

What would be the easiest way to go about this?

*Edit: It seems I'm trying to oversimplify the problem so here's some more detail:*

Here's a fraction of the schema I'm using:

```
create table `house` (`id` int not null auto_increment, `name` varchar(255) null, primary key (`id`))
create table `seller` (`id` int not null auto_increment, `name` varchar(255) null, primary key (`id`))
create table `user` (`id` int not null auto_increment, `name` varchar(255) null, primary key (`id`))
create table `selling_details` (`id` int not null auto_increment, `details` varchar(255) not null, date datetime not null, `house_id` int null, `seller_id` int null, `user_id` int not null, primary key (`id`))

alter table `selling_details` add index `FK_selling_details_user` (`user_id`), add constraint `FK_selling_details_user` foreign key (`user_id`) references `user` (`id`)
alter table `selling_details` add index `FK_selling_details_house` (`house_id`), add constraint `FK_selling_details_house` foreign key (`house_id`) references `house` (`id`)
alter table `selling_details` add index `FK_selling_details_seller` (`seller_id`), add constraint `FK_selling_details_seller` foreign key (`seller_id`) references `seller` (`id`)
```

Now, just to make things really complicated too, there may be many rows in the `selling_details` table linking `house` and `seller`. If there is one or more of these rows present, I only want the one with the most recent `date`; if there's no such row, still return the house and seller combination as in the example results above.

Comment: If you have a specific schema and posted it, that would help make the answer directly usable.

Comment: I was in a bit of a hurry when I posted this, but I updated the information. I was oversimplifying the problem a bit to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross join the house and sellers, then left join to find any details for the combination

```
select h.house_id, s.seller_id, sd.details
from houses h
cross join sellers s
left join selling_details sd
    on sd.seller_id = s.seller_id
    and sd.house_id = h.house_id
order by h.house_id, s.seller_id
```

Comment: I ended up using multiple queries just to make things easier on myself, but pointing out cross joins made me look it up and they will come in handy for the future, so thanks.